# Is it OK if paper tape doesn't cover the whole length of a seam?

Tags: drywall

Is it OK if paper tape doesn't cover the whole length of a seam? i.e. The tape is centred over the seam, but is an inch or two short of the edge on either side side. Will this result in cracking?

For context the walls in question ade really narrow - around 16-18" and the seams are running horizontally if that makes a difference.

Comment: I would say yes, there will be a good chance of cracking where there is no tape.

Comment: Maybe a bit of mesh tape to touch up, if you've done this already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not OK. The tape prevents the mud from drying too quick in the seam and keeps it from cracking. The tape also ensures a smooth seam if done properly. You might not even notice the ends where the tape is short... until you paint the walls and the light hits it a certain way. Why doesn't  the tape cover the entire length of the seam?

Comment: Thanks for the details. This was done by my contractor and I just noticed.

Comment: Seems like a good opportunity to call the contractor back...